# How should login bans work?

Tags: security, brute-force

I have set up a login system. If your maximum quota of *failed attempts per IP or per username* is exceeded, the login page will ask you to solve a captcha until you log in. I thought to remove all records when the user successfully logs in (removes the records which have your IP **or** your username). However, this has a flaw.

Suppose this is the `attempts` table.

```
       IP | Username
----------+---------
127.0.0.1 |  jeff   
----------+---------
127.0.0.1 |  jeff
----------+---------
127.0.0.1 |  jeff
----------+---------
127.0.0.1 |  jeff
----------+---------
```

Now, suppose the client `127.0.0.1` logs in with the username `atwood`. Now, there are no more records about him: he can keep bruteforcing the other user without having to deal with captchas.

How can I prevent this workaround?